# Python QWebEnginePage (PyQt5) crash

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.5, qwebenginepage

Hello everyone I just trying to use pyqt5 (I used python-3.5) to render html.
I implemnted this class (Page) to do this tasks:

```
#This is the Main.py.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import UrlDl

class Page(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self, html, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.html = None
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
        self.setHtml(html, QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()


    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
        print('Load finished')



    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str
        #print("quit called")
        self.app.quit()

def main():
    url = ''#Base_Url
    with open('C:\\HTML_FILE_PATH', "r") as text:
        url_html = text.read()
    for i in range(10):
        page = Page(url_html, url)
        print(page.html)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I am running this class with a html (allready downloaded) and base url in this way:

```
page = Page(html, base_url)
```

this code is working few times (*in for loop*). But after few running I got exceptions:

> [15952:7692:0115/010330.922:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to
>   move the cache: 5
>   [15952:7692:0115/010330.922:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move
>   cache folder C:\Users...\QtWebEngine\Default\GPUCache to
>   C:\Users....\QtWebEngine\Default\old_GPUCache_000
>   [15952:7692:0115/010330.922:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(134)] Unable to
>   create cache
>   [15952:7692:0115/010330.922:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(570)] Shader
>   Cache Creation failed: -2
>   [15952:7692:0115/010331.027:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to
>   move the cache: 5
>   [15952:7692:0115/010331.027:ERROR:cache_util.cc(134)] Unable to move
>   cache folder C:\Users...\QtWebEngine\Default\Cache to
>   C:\Users...\QtWebEngine\Default\old_Cache_000
>   [15952:7692:0115/010331.027:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(134)] Unable to
>   create cache

When it crash it also exit with strange exit code(not zero). Its look like:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

It exit because the line `self.app.quit()` (in "Callable" function in my class).

**How to solve it??**

Comment: show complete code

Comment: @eyllanesc Updated